# regular expressions excluding words that begin with a semi colon

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to figure out how to include certain word groups and exclude others.I have this string for example

```
string1="HI:MYDLKJL:ajkld? :JKLJBLKJD:DKJL? app?"
```

I want to find `HI:MYDLKJL:ajkld?` and  `app?` but not `:JKLJBLKJD:DKJL?` because it begins with a : I have made this code but it still includes the :JKLJBLKJD:DKJL? just ignoring the : in the front

```
match3=re.findall("[A-Za-z]{1,15}[:]{0,1}[A-Za-z]{0,15}[:]{0,1}[A-Za-z]{0,15}[:]{0,1}[A-Za-z]{0,15}[\?]{1}",string1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual pattern is pretty simple to specify. But, you'll *also* need to specify a look-behind to handle the second term appropriately.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))[^:]\S+\?', string1)
['HI:MYDLKJL:ajkld?', 'app?']
```

The regex means "any expression that does not start with a colon but ends with a question mark".

```
(?:             # lookbehind 
    (?<=\s)     # space 
    |           # OR
    (?<=^)      # start-of-line metachar
) 
[^:]            # anything that is not a colon
\S+             # one or more characters that are not a space
\?              # literal question mark
```

A simple word boundary does not work because `\b` will also match the boundary between `:` and `JKLJBLKJD`... no bueno, hence the lookbehind.

Comment: ends with a space? I want it to end with \? thats what your code does though right?

Comment: @Bob Yes, sorry. That was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach

```
>>> string1="HI:MYDLKJL:ajkld? :JKLJBLKJD:DKJL? app?"
>>> string1.split()
['HI:MYDLKJL:ajkld?', ':JKLJBLKJD:DKJL?', 'app?']

# filter out elements not needed
>>> [s for s in string1.split() if not s.startswith(':')]
['HI:MYDLKJL:ajkld?', 'app?']
```

Or, using the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module

```
>>> string1="HI:MYDLKJL:ajkld? :JKLJBLKJD:DKJL? app?"
>>> regex.findall(r'(?:^|\s):\S+(*SKIP)(*F)|\S+', string1)
['HI:MYDLKJL:ajkld?', 'app?']
```

- `(?:^|\s):\S+(*SKIP)(*F)` will effectively ignore strings starting with `:`
- `(?:` means [non-capturing group](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups)